# Device tree phandle hex to reference node

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi4, device-tree

Is it possible to derive the reference node from a phandle?

For example, my RPI 4 has this:

```
mmcnr@7e300000 {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-mmc\0brcm,bcm2835-sdhci";
    reg = <0x7e300000 0x100>;
    interrupts = <0x00 0x7e 0x04>;
    clocks = <0x07 0x1c>;
    dmas = <0x0b 0x0b>;
    dma-names = "rx-tx";
    brcm,overclock-50 = <0x00>;
    non-removable;
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <0x1f>;
    bus-width = <0x04>;
    phandle = <0x38>;
};
```

How do I know what node 0x38 is?

Comment: Just to be clear, you not trying to find the node in the live device tree from kernel code, you are trying to find the node within a dtb file (or a decompiled version of the dtb file) from user-space code. Is that correct?

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, I have a dtb and decompiled it to dts. Now I want to know which node 0x38 is.

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own code making use of the libfdt library. After slurping the whole dtb into a buffer, useful functions for this particular problem are `fdt_check_full` or `fdt_check_header` for sanity checking, `fdt_node_offset_by_phandle` to get the offset to the node that has a specified phandle value, and `fdt_get_path` to get the path that leads to the node offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through all the nodes using of_find_all_nodes() starting by passing  parameter to this function as NULL. This function returns device_node .. You can compare the returned device_node->phandle with 0x38, if it matches. That is the node

Comment: Good option, but I need to parse it locally and not on the system. Do you recommend software (that runs on Linux)? Otherwise my weekend will be filled with joyful programming :D

Comment: Also, is `device_node->phandle` the referred `phandle` in, in my example, the `mmcnr` node? So my `mmcnr phandle` can have a different `phandle` in the `device_node struct` than the `phandle property` in `struct property *properties;`, which will have a representation of `phandle=<0x38>`?